# iPhone opens my responsive site as if it were just 320px wide

Tags: html, css, iphone

I know that the latest iPhones have a higher number of pixels horizontally than just 320. But my responsive site when opened on iPhone opens as if it were opening on a phone which is just 320px wide. On Galaxy, it opens fine by utilizing more pixels. How can I prevent iPhone's browser from zooming into the site and make my site utilize more of iPhone's pixels horizontally?

I have already tried  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />` but that didn't work.

What is the fix for this?

thanks

Comment: The meta looks OK. Can you provide a link to a webpage where this happens?

Comment: @MrLister its a client site currently being developed so can't post the link, but here's a similar site(parent theme) https://themes.shopify.com/themes/symmetry/styles/beatnik/preview.
I want the site to look the same as it looks on a galaxy phone. But for some reason, the site appears as if it were just 320px wide on iphone(as if it were being viewed on older phones). How can I make the site to take more width(pixels) on the iphone?